# I can't remember the name of the property when $f(x \oplus y) = f(x) \oplus f(y)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

When  $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$, we say that the function $f$ is ... over the $+$ operator. I can't remember the name of that property . Please help.

**Update:**

I din't know how to write the $\oplus$ operator, when I first wrote the question. Sorry about that. What I really wanted was:

When  $f(x\oplus y) = f(x) \oplus f(y)$, we say that the function $f$ is ... over the $\oplus$ operator. I can't remember the name of that property . Please help.

Comment: Luckily I noticed to changed your question before I posted my answer

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, I din't know how to write the $\oplus$ operator

Comment: $f$ is stable under $\oplus$?

Comment: Linear?${{}{{}}$

Comment: this function is additive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated answer: the only thing I can think of that fits the more general case is that $f$ *distributes* over $\oplus$, or that it is distributive.

Comment: Hi Arthur. A million thanks for prompt answer. Unfortunatelly I made a mistake when writing it, my bad. Is updated. Can you check this, please? Thanks again

Comment: @ElMarce I can only think of one word that might fit...

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be that f preserves the operation.